# Data type of Function Argument in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have defined a simple function in Python that takes 'Strings' as an argument and tried to manipulate the code a bit, and saw a difference while calling the function with those two codes.

This is the first code:

```
def my_name(first_name,last_name):
    first_name = input('enter the first name:')
    last_name = input('enter the last name:')
    print(first_name+' ' + last_name)

my_name('first_name','last_name')
```

In this program, I need to use quotation marks with the argument and if I don't use them I get an error. Why is this so?

But for the second program, I don't need to use quotation mark if I still use them, I don't get any find of error but for the previous program I have to use quotation otherwise it results in an error.

Please help.
Here are snippets of my code:
First code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zh4s.png)

Getting error while running without quotation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGgQ.png)

Second code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzCYY.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In the first code you are passing 2 strings as a parameter to the ``my_name`` function, if you remove the lines that have the input() it will print ``first_name last_name`` and when you remove the quotation you are passing as a parameter 2 variables that are not have been initialized and need to receive values (which happens in the second code).

Comment: But, when we store string in any variable then we don't need to put the quotation mark around the variable name while running the code, python just consider it as a variable so, why this time a variable needs to be enclosed in a quotation mark

Comment: Do not use images for code or tracebacks or output.  Copy and paste the text into the question.  Format tracebacks and output (usually) as code.

Comment: Ok sure, I didn't know about it actually. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Given `def f(arg): pass`, the call `f(s)` fails with `NameError: name 's' is not defined` because the name `s` in the call is not defined.  If you add `s = 'some string'` before the call, then the call works because `s` *is* defined.  This and related matters is explained in the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Why is this so, I am asking a user to type his or her name in the first_name and last_name variables so, how come these two variables are not defined?

Comment: Is this because as I used this inside the fuction so, its scope becomes limited? Can any please provide the reasoning behind it as why I need to use enclose the variable inside quotation during the fuction call.

Comment: In any function, the code within the `def` is not executed until the function is called, and the scope of names bound within a function is normally limited to the function.  So `first_name` is not defined when calling the function.

Comment: Also note that `first_name=input...` within the function throws away any value passed as the `first_name` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, but accept my apologies as I am unable to understand what you are tyring to say so, can you please explain the same to me by providing some kind of example. That would be a great help if you could so.